# This site can’t be reached: https://cran.r-project.org/

Tags: html, r, cran

I'm trying to install R, but when I go to the page (https://cran.r-project.org/), it gives me this message: This site can’t be reached.

May you tell me why is this happening? I would like to know if it's happening to everyone, or it's just me, and if there's a way to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: The site appears to be down at the moment

Comment: Useful site: https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/cran.r-project.org?proto=https

Comment: You should use `cloud.r-project.org` instead.  It's a mirror of CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the answer since it has been a year. I am confused too - there seems to be two different websites. Rstudio has been rebranded to posit it seems since I get redirected to this link.

https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/

and on here, you can both install R and RStudio. Here, it says install R via this website
https://cran.rstudio.com/

Comment: At the time the question was posted, https://cran.r-project.org/ was down, hence the error. Thanks